# Difference between repeated measures data and longitudinal data

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, terminology

What is the difference between repeated measures data and longitudinal data?

**My answer**
I think that for repeated measures data, the dependent variable can be measured more than once for each observation, but each time that is measured, it can be of form regardless or not. In longitudinal data, the dependent variable always will be measured in time.

Comment: What does "of form regardless or not" mean in this context?

Comment: Each observation is collected of form independent, that is without influence of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally, they mean the same thing: subjects were measured more than once for the same kind of outcome. They differ in connotation in that "repeated measures" suggests measurements separated by a relatively short amount of time (e.g., minutes, hours) whereas "longitudinal data" suggests longer intervals (e.g., days, years). This may just be an artifact of field differences (e.g., experimental psychologists talk about "repeated measures" and public-health researchers talk about "longitudinal data").